# Moved Ubuntu16.04 to T450s, WiFi stopped working, but

Tags: 16.04

I have a Lenovo T430 laptop running Ubuntu 16.04. Now I decide to upgrade to a T450s. So I took out the SSD and put in the T450s. It boots up fine, but couldn't find the WiFi device. However if I boot it up from a Ubuntu 16.04 desktop image USB stick, Wifi works perfectly as everything else.

So it seem only the driver is missing. But how can I install only what is missing and avoid a reinstall?

thanks much for any insight!

Comment: First you need to know the model of the wifi card, so why not add the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 Net`.

Answer (score 0):

After moving the SSD back to the T430, the Wifi stopped working there too at first, but after a reboot, it worked fine.

Inspired at the experience, I moved the SSD back to T450s and reboot it, wifi suddenly is working.

So it seems the system figured out it wasn't working and installed the right driver automatically.